# Why is my performance so poor when accessing elements in an unordered_map?

Tags: c++, optimization, component-based

I'm trying to implement a component based architecture on a game engine project. Each `GameObject` has an `unordered_map` that holds a pointer to `Component` base class. At this point, I only have one component derived class, which is the `Transform` class. I wanted to implement this component based architecture similar to the Unity's convention: I want to get a component of game object by calling the member template function like `GetComponent<Transform>()`.

Here are the headers:

**Component.h**

```
enum type{
    TRANSFORM   // more will be added later
};

class Component // base class
{
public:
    Component() : _owner(NULL) {}
    virtual ~Component(){}
    static type Type;

protected:
    GameObject* _owner;
};
```

**Transform.h**

```
class Transform : public Component
{
public:
    Transform();
    ~Transform();
    static type Type;

    void Rotate(float deg);

    // to be encapsulated later on
    Vector2D _position;
    float _rotation;
    Vector2D _scale;
};
```

**GameObject.h**

```
class GameObject
{
public:
    GameObject();
    ~GameObject();

    void Update();
    //and more member functions

    template<class T>
    T* GetComponent();
private:
    // some more private members
    unordered_map<type, Component*> _componentList; // only 1 component of each type
};

template<class T>
T* GameObject::GetComponent()
{       
    return static_cast<T*>(_componentList[T::Type]);
}
```

---

My initial implementation used `std::vector` for keeping `Component*` and the application ran at 60 fps (I also have a frame rate controller, which just limits the FPS to 60). When I changed to the `unordered_map` for accessing those component pointers, the performance went downhill to 15 FPS.

[image]

I only draw two quads and I call `GetComponent<Transform>()` only 6 times per frame at this point, so there is not much going on in the scene.

---

**What I tried?**

I tried to use `const char*`, `std::string`, `type_info` and finally `enum type` as key values for the `unordered_map` but nothing really helps: all implementations got me 15-16 FPS.

What causes this performance issue? How can I isolate the issue?

<sub>I hope I provided enough detail, feel free to ask for more code if necessary</sub>

Comment: The first thing to do would be to run a profiler on that...

Comment: And I see a couple of flaws: if you want a new component type that is not in your engine, you're screwed because your types are hard coded as an enum. And using RTTI just like Unity does in c++ is questionable. You could try to look for a way to associate your component types as integers (find a way to hash their names at compilation time, for instance), defined in the children classes.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt this is my first engine/game project written in C++ only, so its a heavy learning process for me. I know the `enum` stuff is pretty tedious, I'm really unhappy my initial approach didn't work as I expected :| Thanks for you valuable input! I should definitely read more...

Comment: Remove the frame limiter, test FPS without it.

Comment: Is it compiled in debug or release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I was doing something really wrong. The problem was in the gameloop where I updated the components.

```
for (auto component : _componentList){
    //   ^ not reference -> lots of ctor/dtor calls -> low fps
    if(component) component->Update();
```

Answer (score 2):

**I suspect your problem is because cache misses sky rocketed once you introduced `unordered_map`..**

Well, storing `vector<Component*>` isn't the most cache friendly strategy, yet when you used unordered_map, **you introduced another level (or two) of indirection**, `unordered_map` is hash table with array of linked lists, so when you lookup an item, first it needs to hash the key to lookup the linked list, and then search through the list for the component. Also storing pointers for Component, doesn't guarantee the objects are contiguous in memory unless you are using a special kind of memory pools/allocators.

For better in-depth discussion I suggest you read [Sean Middleditch Slot Maps](http://seanmiddleditch.com/data-structures-for-game-developers-the-slot-map/) and [optimization patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/optimization-patterns.html), [component design](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/component.html) from [Game Programming Patterns](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/contents.html).

Comment: In this case, ignore cache misses. 6 lookups per frame don't lead to 15 FPS. Most implementations easily support at least half a million lookups/sec on an average desktop CPU.

Comment: @snake5 IMO cache misses is the only issue that can be deduced from the info given in the question (this happens when he changes vector to unordered_map). Unless he is doing sth else horribly wrong. I don't think the answer deserves a -1.

Comment: You assume that he's telling the whole story and that the rest of the code is good, that's almost never the case. He most likely is doing something horribly wrong - note that he has a frame rate limiter and he's on Windows - the system with the most imprecise timers I've ever seen.  P.S. I didn't give you a -1. :)

Comment: @snake5 I just noticed the frame limiter. It could be that, or he messed sth else up. Also I agree 6 lookups shouldn't be a suspect.

Comment: @concept3d turns out i was doing something horribly wrong as you suspected. When iterating through gameobjects in the scene in the Update() function, I didnt use references in the foreach loop, hence all the temporary copies of gameobjects just slowed down the whole process. Although your answer doesn't apply to my case, it's a good heads up for me for my future designs. Shall I even delete my question?

Comment: @Varaquilex don't delete your question, just post an answer... and honestly that's is why I dislike foreach loops..

Comment: @concept3d Do you also dislike every function that must receive a non-basic type of object without copying? Plenty of users here get that wrong, too. Having to remember to reference-qualify unless there's a specific reason not to is just something we must internalise with C++. Other languages' implicit pass-by-ref, if perhaps more common, doesn't innately make more sense. It's just a convention either way, like many others that need remembered. Writing off for-each loops due to that seems very excessive, and like a slippery slope that ultimately ends in you not being able to use C++ at all. :P

Comment: @underscore_d No, I take this on case by case. I wrote this 3 yrs ago. I dont remember my rational and dont have time to go through that again. But i think the op probably used new which did alot of random allocations and causing alot of cache misses. You are trying to generalize what am saying which is not true. I am also not in game dev anymore....